# CGI and xmlhttrequest JSON response

Tags: json, perl, cgi

I'm doing a cgi script to read XMLHttpRequest and it will response with Json. 
The part of reading the request is done (example: register, adding nick and pass to database).
But, how can I create the response???In JSON.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Google for queries like "perl cpan json"...

Read this: http://metacpan.org/pod/JSON

Comment: On Google you can find some interesting answers on some complex questions or problems though.

Comment: In my experience, many of those are crap (e.g. "PERL tutorials" from 2000 written by people who didn't really understand perl).

Comment: Humm it looks nice. It teaches methods to create JSON in Perl, but unfortunately I can't discover how to send JSON to client :(!
Do you know this???

Comment: quick and dirty, you just print it to STDOUT. I mean, just 'print $json;' will work OK.

Comment: TOP  user1883592 ;) ! So , when xmlhttprequest.readystate=4 my javascript will interpret the json sent by STDOUT , that's it? Thanks a lot